# mypy - Item "None" of "Optional[CustomAttrsModel]" has no attribute "country"

Tags: python, mypy

When I run mypy checkings I am getting an error. I am no able to ignore it or turn it off the strict optional checking. It there a way to solve this.

Here is the line that is throwing the error:

```
 if tree.data.attributes.custom != JAPAN:
```

where `attributes` is declared as:

```
class TreeAttributesModel(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[TreeId]
    name: Optional[str] = None
    status: StatusEnum
    custom: Optional[CustomAttrsModel] = None
```

and `CustomAttrsModel` is declared as it follows:

```
class CustomAttrsModel(BaseModel):
    seller: Optional[str]
    buyed_at: Optional[datetime]
    country: Optional[Union[CountryEnum, str]]
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Could you add what is the error?

Comment: can you provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's not clear to me what is trying to access `country` given your code

Comment: Your `tree.data.attributes.custom` is declared as `Optional`. If the real line is `if tree.data.attributes.custom.country != JAPAN`, then you have to check that `tree.data.attributes.custom` is not `None` before accessing `.country` (if not - then please make this error reproducible, the code you show cannot produce error in title).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to tweak your snippets a bit to get a MWE, but [here we go](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3dd2df836ada48468fd1ae11eedfcbda):

```
import enum
import dataclasses

from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, Union


class StatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    OK = enum.auto()
    NOK = enum.auto()

class CountryEnum(enum.Enum):
    JAPAN = enum.auto()
    RAPTURE = enum.auto()

@dataclasses.dataclass
class TreeAttributesModel:
    id: Optional[str]
    name: Optional[str]  # = None had to remove default, attribs w/o default cannot follow attribs w/ one
    status: StatusEnum
    custom: Optional[CustomAttrsModel] = None
    
@dataclasses.dataclass
class CustomAttrsModel:
    seller: Optional[str]
    buyed_at: Optional[datetime]
    country: Optional[Union[CountryEnum, str]]

custom = CustomAttrsModel(seller="test", buyed_at=None, country=CountryEnum.JAPAN)
attribs = TreeAttributesModel(id="test", name="test", status=StatusEnum.OK, custom=custom)

assert attribs.custom is not None  # this is typed as being optional, so make sure it isn't None
assert attribs.custom.country is not None  # same as above
result = attribs.custom.country != CountryEnum.JAPAN
```

The message is: just use `assert something is not None` whenever `something` is `Optional` ;)